# How to enable systemd user sessions for remote logins on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, ssh, systemd

I am trying to enable systemd user sessions on my CentOS 7 server. All the pieces seem to be there, and I have also run `loginctl enable-linger <user>`, but I don't have a systemd user session (or a session D-Bus).

What do I need to configure in order to have systemd user sessions started with my SSH logins, and long-term for linger-enabled users?

I successfully see my login session with `loginctl list-sessions`; however, there is no user session `systemd` process associated with it, and any `systemctl --user` operation fails.

Comment: You might want to clarify, I [was able](https://dpaste.de/MJ5P) to see my ssh login session with `loginctl` on a vanilla CentOS 7 install.

Comment: @Bratchley I have clarified; I can see the login session with `loginctl`, but there is not a systemd user session (usable with `systemctl --user`).

Comment: Michael, has the situation improved with subsequent upgrades to systemd-218 or higher? (re: Kyle's answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug.

[sys-apps/systemd-205 - systemd --user: Failed to create root cgroup hierarchy: Permission denied](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67471)

The OP started using systemd-218 before it worked for him.