# Make process not exit, when exiting from SSH terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line, process, background-process

I just run bitcoind in centOS server. I run the following command

```
nohup ./bitcoind > out & disown
```

Then I exit the SSH terminal, and the process is automatically closed. Is there any way to make this process run as a background process, after closing `ssh`?

Os: CentOS-7

Answer (score 1):

CentOS *version 7 or newer* I suppose?

This looks like an effect of `systemd` session management: when the user's session ends, any processes belonging to that session are automatically terminated.

If that's the cause, the solution requires two steps. First, your user account needs a permission to let processes linger on after the user's session ends:

```
loginctl enable-linger <username>
```

Granting that permission may or may not require admin rights, depending on choices made by the system administrator and/or default settings of a particular Linux distribution.

Then you'll need to use `systemd-run` instead of the old `nohup` to start your long-term background process.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering, The command "loginctl enable-linger <username>" is working. But I the process is automatically stop when the terminal is closed. Have any suggestion.

Comment: Hey... Please respond

Comment: According to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188895/258991), if your CentOS is not up to date with patches, it might be a known bug in `systemd`. Also, if you are not the server administrator, the admin may have taken steps to stop regular users leaving lingering processes around; if that's the case, you'll need to talk to that administrator.

Comment: The admin already give the permission for lingering processes. But I the process is automatically stop when the terminal is closed. Have any suggestion.

Comment: If the CentOS system is up to date and you already used `systemd-run` instead of `nohup` after enabling lingering, then I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: sorry, I don't used systemd-run. I only used nohup. If I use systemd-run, I will get the the error Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory

Comment: I run the command "systemd-run ./bitcoind"